# .NET 6 SPA With Angular 9

Tags: .net, angular, single-page-application, angular9

I am trying to create a new .NET 6 application using `dotnet new angular -o <Project Name>`
and it creates it with Angular 12. However, I have to use Angular 9 due to my requirements.

Is there any way to specify which Angular version is used in the `dotnet new` command?
If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Create an empty ASP.NET Core project, and separately create an Angular 9 project using angular-cli (not VS), then manually combine the two.